# What "wiring" pin numbers on Pi Zero pinout diagram mean

Tags: wiring

On the below [diagram](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/6/7/6/PiZero_1.pdf) I understand what position (on the board), GPIO (abstract Pi GPIO numbers) and BCM (SoC pin numbers) pin numbers mean, but what's the meaning of the "wiring"?

[image: Pi Zero Wiring diagram]

Comment: The BEST option is to ignore them. It was a misguided idea in the first place and is not supported. Use BCM like every other library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Wiring"* refers to the [wiring pi library](http://wiringpi.com/), and its associated command line utility - `gpio`.

If you have installed Wiring Pi, you may list/print the relationship between the various RPi GPIO designations as follows:

```bsh
$ gpio readall
```

The result on my RPi 4B is:

```
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 4B--+---+------+---------+-----+-----+  
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |  
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+  
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |  
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |   IN | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |  
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |   IN | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |  
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 1 | IN   | TxD     | 15  | 14  |  
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | IN   | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 4B--+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

#### ICYI:

The original [wiring Pi library](http://wiringpi.com/) was developed by Gordon Henderson, and maintained by him until August, 2019. Wiring Pi remains available through [GitHub](https://github.com/WiringPi), but its future is not entirely clear. As the [current maintainers have indicated](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi):

> ... this repository has become a mirror of the last "official" source release, plus a fork facilitating updates to support newer hardware (primarily for use by the ports) and fix bugs.

Comment: Thanks! Already installed wiring pi and ran this command. Really confusing with 2 different GPIO pin numberings on the diagram from the datasheet and these. I guess they had a reason.

Comment: Yes - it can be a bit confusing. The sources for GPIO documentation that I've found most useful are the [RPi Pinout Page](https://pinout.xyz/#), and the `gpio readall` output. The RPi Pinout especially so as you can 'click' a pin & get useful details that you might have to search for somewhere else. And here's [another answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120013/83790) that may have useful info.

Comment: I have written a few replacements for `gpio readall` using various libraries.[GPIOreadall](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123749/8697) shows the ACTUAL configured function (rather than the default), including pullup and works on Raspberry Pi OS (Stretch & Buster) without any additional libraries.

Answer (score 1):

They are numbers which may be used by the wiringPi C library and some software built on that library.

See http://wiringpi.com/pins/